# validation error regarding the validation file in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am calling a validation request but i am getting this error.

Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateFile, does not exist.

My UserRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=> 'string|required|max:255',
            'username'=> 'string|required|max:255|alpha_dash',
            'avatar'=>'file,|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:2048',
            'email'=> 'email|required|string',
            'password'=>'required|min:10|string|confirmed',
            'background'=>'file,|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:2048',
            'description'=>'string|max:255'
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'A name is required',
            'username.required' => 'A username is required',
            'email.required' => 'An email is required',
            'password.required' => 'A password is required',
            'description' => 'A description should be string',

        ];
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\File ;
use App\User;
use Hash;
use Session;

public function update(User $user,UserRequest $request)
    {
        
        $user->update(['name'=>request('name'),'username'=>request('username'),'email'=>request('email'),'password'=> Hash::make(request('password')),'avatar'=>$path,'background'=>$background,'description'=>request('description')]);

        Session::flash('success', 'You have successfully updated a post!');
       return redirect($user->path())->with(['message'=>'Profile updated']);
    }
```

my blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <h1 class="text-gray-700 text-2xl font-bold text-center">Edit Profile</h1>
    <div class="mt-5 mb-6">
        <img src="{{$user->avatar()}}" alt=""
             class="rounded-full mr-2  bottom-0 transform  "
             width="150px" style="transform: translateX(16.5rem);" >
    </div>
    
    <form method="POST"  action="{{$user->path() }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
        <div id="flip" class="p-5 bg-gray-200">Basic Info</div>
        <div id="panel">
            <div class="mb-6 mt-6">
                <label for="avatar">Select Profile to Upload</label>
                <input id="avatar" type="file" class="@error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror" name="avatar">
                @error('avatar')
                <div class="text-red-800">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" class="@error('name') is-invalid @enderror border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" name="name" value="{{$user->name}}">
                @error('name')
                <div class="text-red-800">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="@error('username') is-invalid @enderror border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" value="{{$user->username}}">
                @error('username')
                <div class="text-red-800">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="@error('email') is-invalid @enderror border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" value="{{$user->email}}">
                @error('email')
                <div class="text-red-800">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="@error('password') is-invalid @enderror border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" >
                @error('password')
                <div class="text-red-800">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="password-confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" name="password-confirm" class="@error('password-confirm') is-invalid @enderror border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" >
                @error('password-confirm')
                <div class="text-red-800">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>



        </div>
        <div id="main" class="p-5 bg-gray-200">Background</div>
        <div id="child">
            <div class="mb-6 mt-6">
                <label for="background">Select Background image to Upload</label>
                <input id="background" type="file" class="@error('background') is-invalid @enderror" name="background">
                @error('background')
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-6">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <input id="description" type="text"  name="description" class="@error('description') is-invalid @enderror border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" value="{{$user->description}}">
                @error('description')
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-6">
            <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded py-2 px-4 hover:bg-blue-800'">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#flip").click(function(){
                $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
            });
            $("#main").click(function(){
                $("#child").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

I have tried the solutions available on stack overflow but still none of them work
Does anyone know why am i getting this error?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `file,|` remove the comma here in `'background'=>'file,|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:2048'`

Comment: now i am getting this error  **The file "C:\xampp\tmp\php2028.tmp" does not exist **

Comment: Change to `'avatar'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:2048',` and make sure you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on form

Comment: i tried changing the UserRequest to Request , it works fine , i dont't know why it is giving error on UserRequest

Comment: It was the issue  in the ``` 'avatar'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:2048', ``` , but now when i add confirmed in the password , it does not give error even if i enter wrong password

Comment: When you upload a file it is moved to the temp folder but unless you move it to storage it will probably be lost shortly afterwards. Read [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads) on how you can store the file

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma in these validation lines.

1. 'avatar'=>'file`,`|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:2048',
2. 'background'=>'file`,`|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:2048',

Comment: now i am getting this error **The file "C:\xampp\tmp\php2028.tmp" does not exist**

Comment: the issue regarding the image is solved now. It was the issue in the ``` 'avatar'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:2048', ``` , but now when i add confirmed in the password , it does not give error even if i enter wrong password

Comment: make sure you have two input for the password, the first field has a name (password) and the second filed has name (password_confirmation).

Comment: check the name of the password inputs. must be (password, password_confirmation).

Comment: i did as you said but still not working ```  
 'password'=>'required|min:10|string|confirmed', ```   ```<input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="@error('password') is-invalid @enderror border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" >
                 <input id="password_confirmation" type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" >
               ```

Comment: in validation message, set a message for ( password.confirmed )

Answer (score 0):

Add password.confirmed in messages array.

```
'password.confirmed' => 'YOUR ERROR MESSAGE',
```